# NEW Google Drive Android API - Metadata of unfinished file prematurely available

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

This problem is directed to the [Google Drive Android API support team](https://developers.google.com/drive/support). It may be considered a bug or just heads-up note. When testing GDAA I've run into this problem:

1. I created a file asynchronyously
2. Before the file was ready, I performed a search and found the file by name
3. Managed to retrieve it's metadata with no sign of problems
4. Attempt to use the metadata blew up (obviously)

The point is: Shouldn't the file search or metadata retrieval indicate that file is not ready / does not exist yet? Or is there a method to check that?

Here are code snippets to demonstrate the problem (simplified - not a production level code)

**primitive # 1 create a file asynch**

```
  void createFileAsync(final DriveFolder fldr, final String name, 
                                                          final String mime, final byte[] buff) {
    final DriveId  dId = fldr.getDriveId();
    Drive.DriveApi.newContents(_gac).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
      @Override public void onResult(ContentsResult rslt) {
        if (!rslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) return; 
        DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(_gac, dId);
        MetadataChangeSet meta = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                                       .setTitle(name).setMimeType(mime).build();
        folder.createFile(_gac, meta, rslt.getContents()).setResultCallback(
                                                          new ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
          @Override public void onResult(DriveFileResult rslt) {
            _dFile = rslt.getStatus().isSuccess() ? rslt.getDriveFile() : null; 
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

**primitive # 2 find the file by name - with wait**

```
  public DriveFile findFirst(String name) {
    Filter filtr = Filters.and(
      Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false),
      Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, name)
    ); 
    Query qry = new Query.Builder().addFilter(filtr).build(); 
    MetadataBufferResult rslt = (Drive.DriveApi.query(_gac, qry).await()
    if (rslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
      MetadataBuffer mdb = null;
      try { 
        mdb = rslt.getMetadataBuffer();
        return Drive.DriveApi.getFile(_gac, mdb.get(0).getDriveId());          
      } finally { if (mdb != null) mdb.close(); } 
    }
    return null;
  }
```

**test / problem scenario :**

```
  GoogleApiClient _gac;   

  DriveFolder fldr = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(_gac);
  byte[] buffer = ("FooBar ").getBytes();

  // create a file async
  DriveFile _dFile = null;
  createFileAsync(fldr, "foo", "text/plain", buffer);

  // file is not ready yet, but FOUND and it's metadata VALID (non-null)
  Metadata md = findFirst("foo").getMetadata(_gac).await().getMetadata();

  // any attempt to use Metadata methods 
  // md.isTrashed(), md.getTitle(), ...
  // blows up until the  createFileAsync() is finished
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not ready"?

Comment: I call createFileAsync(). It gets back immediately (it is async) but the file is actually created later (there are 2 cascaded async callbacks in createFileAsync()). During that time (the file creation is not finished yet), the file can be already found by a call to findFirst() above. You see it if you grep for 'SystemClock.sleep(2000)' here: https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA/blob/master/awaits/MainActivity.java

Comment: Rephrasing: There is some time between entering createFileAsync() and the second onResult(). The app can call Drive.DriveApi.query(...) during that time. Should the file be found during that time using Drive.DriveApi.query(...).await()? It is found and it's metadata is not stable.

Comment: And obviously, you don't have this problem if you use DriveFolder.createFile(_gac, meta, cont).await() since the flow is synchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy to report that the problem disappeared (by intervention ?). The *query by name* on a file that is being created (asynchronously) does not return valid metadata until the creation is complete. Simplified code chunk from primitive #2 above:

```
for (Metadata md : rslt.getMetadataBuffer()) 
   ;  // NO md AVAILABLE until the file creation is completed!!!
```

works correctly now, not enumerating any metadata until 'the file is ready'.