# Incorrect sequence of actions in method with callback

Tags: java, android, callback, google-drive-api

I have next method, that returns `ArrayList<String>`, data from Google Drive account.

```
public int getMetodsList()
{   final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
     System.out.println("1");
    Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient, getIDOfFolder("SomeFolder"))
    .listChildren(MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>()
            {
            @Override
            public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult mdbr) {
                 System.out.println("2");
                for (int i = 0; i < mdbr.getMetadataBuffer().getCount(); i++)
                {  result.add(mdbr.getMetadataBuffer().get(i).getTitle());
                }
                 System.out.println("3");
            } }
        );  
    System.out.println("4");
    return result.size();
```

For help i've added `log` with numbers - `System.out.println("number");` 
   When I invoke this method, `Log` returns me next sequence:
      ***1, 4, 2, 3***.
   So i can't get right `ArrayList`, *return* is invoked before `CallBack()`

Help please, **how can i invoke CallBack **`ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>` before `return`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the asynchronous method, so the output is hardly surprising. When you want to access the folder contents synchronously, use `await`:

> With this release of Google Play services, you now have the option to specify if an API call should execute asynchronously (you will receive a callback once it is finished), or synchronously (the thread will block until the operation has completed). This is achieved by using the classes PendingResult, Result, and Status in the com.google.android.gms.common.api package.
>
> In practice, this means that API operations will return an instance of PendingResult, and you can choose if you want the method to execute asynchronously using setResultCallback or synchronously using await.
> (http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/02/new-client-api-model-in-google-play.html).

Answer (score 0):

In general, your problem is not related to GDAA, but to the fact that ASYNC logic results have to be controlled by either the ***state of global variables*** or by ***callbacks*** (that's a general coding principle). I would definitely recommend you start with "await" versions (you can pull wrapper class ["GooApiClnt" from here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA/blob/master/awaits/MainActivity.java) and wrap your full process in AsyncClass).

You will avoid not only problems in your code (as you demonstrated above), but also other unexpected behaviors like [in this SO nag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381649/new-google-drive-android-api-metadata-of-unfinished-file-prematurely-available/22459540#22459540) - comment #2,#3. And these can be a nightmare, since you don't catch them in debugger, they show only in fullspeed.